# Inconsistent data, not too sure where this is going wrong

Tags: php

I'm currently looping through football [game data](http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/426/fixtures) and trying to calculate all the information which can be [seen here](http://developers.fifteendigital.co.uk/tests/example/).

However somewhere my code seems to be going wrong, [take a look here](http://www.martynleeball.com/), let's use the Hull City team as an example.

So, below is my loop, if an instance of my class isn't made for that team, it's created, if it is made, it uses the existing.

```
  foreach ( $soccerseason->getAllFixtures()->fixtures as $v ) {
          if ($v->status == "FINISHED") {

            // Add data from home team
            if (!array_key_exists($v->homeTeamName, $teamData)) {
              $teamData[$v->homeTeamName] = new Calc(array($v->result->goalsHomeTeam, $v->result->goalsAwayTeam));} else {
              $teamData[$v->homeTeamName]->addData(array($v->result->goalsHomeTeam, $v->result->goalsAwayTeam));
            }
            if (!array_key_exists($v->awayTeamName, $teamData)) {
              $teamData[$v->awayTeamName] = new Calc(array($v->result->goalsHomeTeam, $v->result->goalsAwayTeam));} else {
              $teamData[$v->awayTeamName]->addData(array($v->result->goalsHomeTeam, $v->result->goalsAwayTeam));
            }
          }
        }
```

And here is my `Calc` class, this should be working fine, I can't figure out the issue.

```
class Calc {
    public $config;
    public $win = 0, $draw = 0, $loss = 0, $goalFor = 0, $goalConc = 0;

    public function __construct($payload) {
      // Load config file
      $this->config = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);

      // Add wins, losses, draws, goals for and goal conceived
      $this->addData($payload);
    }

    // Linked data updated, ammend values
    public function calcPlays() {
      return 0 + $this->win + $this->draw + $this->loss;
    }
    public function calcPoints() {
      // Add 0 to ensure value is a int
      return (0 + ($this->win * $this->config->winPoints) +
        ($this->draw * $this->config->drawPoints) +
        ($this->loss * $this->config->lossPoints));
    }
    public function calcGoalDifference() {
      return ($this->goalFor + $this->goalConc);
    }

    public function addData($data) {
      // Append goal data
      $this->goalFor += $data[0]; $this->goalConc += $data[1];

      if ($data[0] > $data[1]) { $this->win++; } elseif
      ($data[0] < $data[1]) { $this->loss++; } elseif
      ($data[0] == $data[1]) { $this->draw++; }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question then?

Comment: Well, why are the figures different?

Comment: Sorry for repeating *So what exactly is your question then?*

Comment: ... well take a look at the data on http://www.martynleeball.com/, looks at wins, it says 6 for Hull City, but on http://developers.fifteendigital.co.uk/tests/example/ it says 3. So somewhere im calculating the figures wrong but can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi Martyn Ball - I think part of the confusion is that you are expecting readers to follow the links to external sites, and figure out exactly what the problem is. You could make it a better question if you [edit] it to include a clear summary of the mismatch you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to swap the data around for when calculating if the away team had won or not.

```
  if (!array_key_exists($v->homeTeamName, $teamData)) {
              $teamData[$v->homeTeamName] = new Calc(array($v->result->goalsHomeTeam, $v->result->goalsAwayTeam));
            } else {
              $teamData[$v->homeTeamName]->addData(array($v->result->goalsHomeTeam, $v->result->goalsAwayTeam));
            }
            if (!array_key_exists($v->awayTeamName, $teamData)) {
              $teamData[$v->awayTeamName] = new Calc(array($v->result->goalsAwayTeam, $v->result->goalsHomeTeam));
            } else {
              $teamData[$v->awayTeamName]->addData(array($v->result->goalsAwayTeam, $v->result->goalsHomeTeam));
            }
```